# Can someone put in an explanation for the regular-expressions tag?

Tags: support, tagging, tag-wikis

For example, the [analytic-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-number-theory) tag has the following helpful explanation:

> Questions on the use of the methods of real/complex analysis in the
>   study of number theory.

Hopefully someone who misunderstands what analytic number theory is would be dissuaded from using that tag on a question that would more properly be tagged number-theory or elementary-number-theory.

But for [regular-expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions), there is no such explanatory text. I imagine that I don't have a high enough reputation score to add such an explanatory text, but even if I do, I'm not exactly sure what a regular expression in mathematics is. The term makes me think of Perl, RegEx and Javascript.

Comment: Looking at it, it should probably be a synonym with [tag:regular-language], but I haven't got the tag score to suggest that synonym.

Comment: A tag wiki summary has [now been added](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1194863/revisions).  I agree with Meelo--it should be merged with regular-language.

Comment: Since there seems to be support for it, I have suggested the synonym [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20131/43288).

Comment: I saw a use of this tag today, still had no description, and I was pretty sure the tag was being misused.